# PhD vs MS in biostatistics

Tags: careers

What are the benefits of getting a PhD vs a masters in biostatistics (besides being a professor)? Will the first job will be the same for both levels? Does the PhD in biostatistics really make a difference in industry?

Comment: Although you mention biostatistics instead of machine learning, this question appears to be the same as [having-a-job-in-data-mining-without-a-phd](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27495/).

Comment: [Possible crosspost.](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2928/ms-vs-phd-in-statistics)

Answer (score 3):

I think it may be different in Europe vs US. In Europe, a Masters degree is sufficient but a PhD will probably get you a higher entry position, faster career progression and more money. Once you're in a company, of course, it's how good you are at the job that really counts.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked in the pharmaceutical industry.  The programming and lower level jobs can go to masters level statisticians but jobs at the level of assistant director and above usually require the PhD.