# What is a poselet?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, computer-vision

I've seen the term "poselet" mentioned a few times (e.g. [A](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27495/having-a-job-in-data-mining-without-a-phd/27497#27497) and [B](http://www.zdnet.com/article/whats-a-poselet-and-why-it-matters-to-facebooks-facial-recognition-accuracy/)) as some sort of construct used in facial recognition.

Comment: Your reference "B" explains that it's a construct *specific* to facial recognition.

Comment: @whuber Ah, I see what you're saying, I've edited my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is:

> A poselet describes a particular part of the human pose under a given
>   viewpoint.

The quote comes from  [this paper](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/human/poselets_iccv09.pdf) "Poselets: Body Part Detectors Trained Using 3D Human Pose Annotations" where I think the term may have been coined.

In the paper mentioned above, they are used as intermediate features in a computer vision pipeline for torso detection, keypoint detection, and people detection. The researchers train a large number of SVM models to identify specific poselets, which are then fed as features into a final top level model which performs the learning tasks. You could see this as feature engineering for a task-specific type of model stacking.